# Is my solution ok or not? Exercise 10 on p.46 in Exercises 2C in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 10 on p.46 in Exercises 2C in this book.

> Exercise 10
> Give an example of a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and a decreasing sequence $E_1\supset E_2\supset\cdots$ of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $$\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k)\neq\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(E_k).$$

My solution is here:

> Let $X:=\mathbb{R}.$
> Let $\mathcal{S}:=2^X.$
> Let $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $\mu(E)=n$ if $E$ is a finite set containing exactly $n$ elements and $\mu(E)=\infty$ if $E$ is not a finite set.
> Then, $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space. (Please see Example 2.55 on p.41 in the book.)
> Let $E_k:=(0,\frac{1}{k}).$
> Then, $E_1\supset E_2\supset\cdots$ holds.
> $\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k)=\mu(\emptyset)=0.$
> $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(E_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\infty=\infty.$
> So, $\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k)\neq\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(E_k).$

Is my solution ok or not?

Comment: It is correct. A more 'natural' example is $E_k=(k,\infty), \mu=$ Lebesgue mesure.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much for your answer.